# Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm getting issue while running Testcase in Appium server "Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

> Original error: 'app Package' option is required "

Comment: What does the server log say?

Answer (score 0):

As per appium below 4 capabilities is utter required :

- platformName
- platformVersion
- deviceName
- app

Below is the JSON Object:

```
 {
        "platformName": "iOS",
        "platformVersion": "11.0",
        "deviceName": "iPhone 7",
        "automationName": "XCUITest",
        "app": "/path/to/my.app"
    }
```

Source:

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

By seen your error it seems your app key either missing in caps or they are worng